# Former2 not finding resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use [Former2](https://former2.com/) to create a CloudFormation template using existing resources.

I setup an IAM user with the ReadOnlyAccess policy and created an access key. I can confirmed my credentials are OK, because I see the message on the Credentials tab:

```
Logged in as: Former2-User @ ##########
```

I have three EC2 instances in this account. However, when I run the scan and go to EC2 resources, I don't see anything listed.

What am I missing that is preventing these resources from being listed?

Comment: Have you selected the right region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always ensure that you select the correct region, both in Former2 and in the AWS Console. 
There might come a day when this straightforward advice will no longer hold true, but today is not that day! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  Still new to AWS.